# How to update YouTube Channel banner using v3 Data Api?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to insert a channel banner using the YouTube v3 Data API. I'm using the .net client library. [This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelBanners/insert) documentation calls for a 3 step process.

1. Upload new banner
2. Extract new banner url from upload response
3. Set bannerExternalUrl to extracted url and call channel update.

My problem is with step 2. If I check the **returned url is null**.  I've double check in Fiddler that the json response does not contain a Url property or value.

Anyone have an idea on how do the banner upload?  Thanks!

```
     var channelBannerResource = new ChannelBannerResource();
     var insertMediaUpload = _serviceV3.ChannelBanners.Insert(channelBannerResource, new FileStream("C:\\banner1.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "image/png");
     insertMediaUpload.Oauth_token = _accessToken;
     var result = insertMediaUpload.Upload();

     //banner Url returns null
     var bannerUrl = insertMediaUpload.ResponseBody.Url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure but, Check this link out (if you haven't already)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelBanners

Your code looks OK on a quick look

One thing to watch out for The image must have a 16:9 aspect ratio and be at least 2120x1192 pixels.

### Update

OK, it appears that you haven't called the channels update method. Something like this

```
Channel updateChannelResponse = youtube.channels()
                .update("god knows what parameter(s) here")
```

Check this link out for more details:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update

Recon after you call this method the URL should be there...I recon...

### Update 2...

Yeah your right, I tried the api explorer but couldn't get that to work either:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channelBanners.insert?_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522url%2522%253A+%2522http%253A%252F%252Ffr.upphotos.net%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2013%252F05%252FFerrari-HD-Widescreen-Large.jpg%2522%250A%257D&

But unfortunately get an error response, weird thing is it's complaining about the 'part' parameter but there is none...could this be a bug in the API, can't imagine many people using this functionality

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.part",
    "reason": "unexpectedPart",
    "message": "contentDetails",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "contentDetails"
 }
}
```

I was expecting this insert to give the URL, fresh out of ideas here.

Comment: I've double checked that the image is the correct aspect ratio and size.  Unfortunately it returns a success message even when I upload an icon size image.  The problem is that it doesn't return the ResponseBody.Url

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Calling Channels.update is step 3 and requires the Url generated from step 2.